# Netstream bufferlength is zero when pausing. How to prevent that?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flash-media-server, netstream

I am using Flex 3 and FMS3 from where I and sending a videostream. I want the user to be able to pause the stream, then resume it. 
For this I am using the methods pause() and resume(). The problem is, when I call pause() the bufferLength is released and equals zero. Accordingly when I resume, the NetStream needs to start buffering all over again, which means I loose all video from the second I paused untill I press resume. And the intention of pause and resume seems of significance.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Please see my other question for this.

[Create server-side DVR application to be able to record DVR in FMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805897/create-server-side-dvr-application-to-be-able-to-record-dvr-in-fms)

If possible, please close this one.

Regards Niclas